# How to return arrays object + count IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

**hi at all** ,I've this code :

```
+(NSArray *)splatterUrls
{
    NSString *jsonString = [ ApiMethod jsonOfStores];
    NSDictionary *results =[jsonString objectFromJSONString];
    NSArray *movieArray = [results objectForKey:@"Seasons"];
    //int i=0;
    // Search for year to match
    for (NSDictionary *movie in movieArray)
    {

        NSNumber *idSplatterMovie = [movie objectForKey:@"Id"];
        // NSLog(@" %@", idSplatterMovie );
        NSArray *try = [movie objectForKey:@"Episodes"];
        // NSLog(@"%@", try);
        for (NSDictionary *op in try) 
        {

            if([idSplatterMovie integerValue] == 46)
            {
                //i++;
                NSArray *movieArrayString = [op objectForKey:@"Url"];
              // NSLog(@" %@", movieArrayString); 
                return movieArrayString;
            }
        } 
    }    
}
```

I want to return movieArrayString with all his objects and how many object contains in it. I think that I should use this method : `+ (id)arrayWithObjects:(const id *)objects count:(NSUInteger)count`. It's possible? If yes, can you tell me how can use it?

Thank you so much!

---

by the way , i have to call splatterUrls method and implement in home.m that it is :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   NSArray *urlSplatter= [GetSplatterUrlsMovie splatterUrls];
    NSLog(@" %@", urlSplatter);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good as it is to me.

Do this to return your movies array, `array` will be equal to your movies array:

`NSArray *array = [self splatterUrls];`

Then to get the count/number of objects in your array do this, `i` is equal to the number of objects in the array:

`int i = [array count];`

Comment: where i put NSArray *array = [self splatterUrls]; ? and how can i return count if there is only NSArray as method?

Comment: Im sorry, you'll have to explain what you want to do more. The method you posted returns an NSArray and and so you can then access that returned result by calling something like `NSArray *array = [self splatterUrls];` It will give you an array equal to what your method returns. If you just need to get the number of objects (the count) of any array then you simply use `[nameOfYourArray count]`.

Comment: ok, when it calling the class that I wrote over( `(NSArray *)urlSplatter `), I have to  call: `- (void) viewDidLoad` for see the `NSLog` result . The problem is that I see only a value in ` NSLog ` . but I saved more values in my array and i can't see all values , do you now understand?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem ??
You return a NSarray ... call the method count on your NSarray object!

Comment: yes but when i call this method he return me just 1 link and not 5 links . i need all links!